# Breaking wave behind a paddle steamer

Tags: waves

While travelling on an 1890's paddle steamer (PS Marion) I noticed that the wake from the paddles consists of a series of waves from each paddle that progressively reduce in amplitude. Some distance back there is virtually no wave but further back again there are one or two breaking waves. These occur at different distances behind the boat on either side, possibly because the boat has a noticeable lean to one side.

Another smaller paddle boat travelling with us had two seperate wakes which merged into a single wake by the time/distance of the breaking wave.

Does anyone know a good reference or explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The large wave that becomes visible at some distance behind the boat is probably part of the hull wave that the whole boat creates as it moves through the water. The hull wave forms as a "pileup" of water in front of the boat that can't quite get out of the way of the bow, and is also known as the "bow wave". As the boat speeds up, the bow wave builds up and at some point the boat engine's entire power output is spent trying to push the hull up the backwards-facing slope of the bow wave, and the boat can go no faster. A train of long-wavelength (of order ~1 hull length) waves trail behind the hull at this point.

The paddle waves are a separate phenomenon.